# NativeScript Theme - setting it to light mode

Tags: angular, nativescript, themes

I'm working on an app with NativeScript 6.8.0 and Angular 8.2.

I am also using NativeScript theme to style my app alongside sass:
https://github.com/NativeScript/theme

The trouble is on iOS the default always seems to be dark mode.

I have used this list key to change it to light mode and it did work but it's only for iOS 13+:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uiuserinterfacestyle

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>    
<string>Light</string>
```

The documentation says that there is a programmatic way to do it as well:
https://github.com/NativeScript/theme#setting-dark-or-light-mode

However, when I tried to do that my app crashed.

I tried to put this code in my app.module file but my app crashed when I tried to open it.

```
import Theme from "@nativescript/theme";

Theme.setMode(Theme.Dark); // Or Theme.Light
```

I also tried to but that code in my app.component file in various lifecycle hooks but the app also crashed.

Lastly, I tried to add it to my SideDrawer on load event but that didn't work either.

```
<RadSideDrawer [drawerTransition]="sideDrawerTransition" [gesturesEnabled]="false" (loaded)="loadedDrawer()">
    <GridLayout tkDrawerContent rows="auto, *" class="sidedrawer sidedrawer-left">
        <ns-side-drawer></ns-side-drawer>
    </GridLayout>
    <page-router-outlet tkMainContent></page-router-outlet>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

Where can I set the theme so that my app does not crash?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these:

https://github.com/NativeScript/theme/issues/277

and the proposed fix (have not tried it yet):

https://github.com/NativeScript/theme/pull/285

I’m currently doing this in main.ts

```
setTimeout(() => {
    Theme.setMode(Theme.Light);
}, 200);
```

Comment: Would you put that in the main app component or in the main app module?

Comment: I've got that in the "loaded" event on my app-component without the timeout. Before that, I had it in main.ts (with the timeout).